# Appending lists in a while loop in Python has the error message 'List index out of range'

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

So I am trying to do a simple loop and for some reason I can't seem to understand why the error message is coming up.

```
earnings = [94500,65377,84524]
deductions = [20000,18000,19000]

tax = [] #empty list
i = -1    #iterative counter
while True:
    i=i+1
    if (earnings[i] > 23000):
        tax.append(0.14*earnings[i])
        continue
    else:
        break
print ('Tax calculation has been completed')
print ('Number of iterations: ',i)
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with the line
    `if (earnings[i] > 23000)`  but I don't know how I would manipulate this.

Comment: You should be initially have  i = 0

Comment: You do not have a check in your loop which checks for if the index has gone out of range, i.e check of i against number of items in list 'earnings'.

Comment: Hi @Snuffles. In this case if I have i=0 then it will miss the first element of the list as the counter operation occurs before the IF statement operation. Even if I were to change it to zero, the error 'List index out of range' would still appear.

Comment: @san - As I am quite new to Python, I was wondering if you would be able to tell me how I could incorporate that into my code?

Comment: @Crumbo0 , I have just posted the answer. Please feel free to accept it and vote it if it helps. :-)

Comment: @san it works! Perfect, thanks! and I shall do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to iterate over the `earnings` list while producing an iteration counter starting from `1`:

```
tax = []
for i, earning in enumerate(earnings, 1):
    if earning <= 23000:
        break
    tax.append(0.14 * earning)

print('Tax calculation has been completed')
print('Number of iterations: ', i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a check in your loop which checks for if the index has gone out of range, i.e check of i against number of items in list 'earnings'. Try this way:

```
earnings = [94500,65377,84524]
deductions = [20000,18000,19000]

tax = [] #empty list
i = -1    #iterative counter
while True:
    i=i+1
    if i >= len(earnings):
        break
    if (earnings[i] > 23000):
        tax.append(0.14*earnings[i])
        continue
print ('Tax calculation has been completed')
print ('Number of iterations: ',i)
```